# PostgreSql maintenance_work_mem increase during Index creatioon

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, indexing

We are doing a migration job on which *GIN* index creation on a JSonB column takes too long time to create. After investigating a bit , we think if we increase the  ***maintenance_work_mem***  limit (it is 120MB now), it would  speed up the things. But We are not sure if this would interrupt current on going index creation/restart the instance . We are running PostgreSql on GCP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `maintenance_work_mem` any time without disturbing active database sessions, but it won't have any effect on `CREATE INDEX` statements that are already running.